# Can't get prompt to show for collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array:

```
@statuses = %w(Foo Bar Bazz)
```

Now I want to create a selection box, where it defaults to a prompt option that says "Choose". This is not working for me for whatever reason:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:status, @statuses, :to_s, :to_s, prompt: '-Choose-') %>
```

It is showing the three options for the select box (Foo, Bar, Bazz) but it isn't showing the prompt option at all.  Instead, it only shows the three options of `Foo`, `Bar`, `Bazz` and defaults to the first one: `Foo`.

Comment: Just to confirm, is this wrapped in a `form_for(@model)` block (as opposed to `form_tag`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
prompt: '-Choose-'
```

to

```
include_blank: '-Choose-'
```

and you must be good.

If you still want to use `prompt` option, do the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:status, @statuses, :to_s, :to_s, { prompt: '-Choose-' }) %>
```